# I want to Encrypt image url so no body can download my image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

This is my view code:

```
 @foreach (var imgpath in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\WaterMark", "*.*"))
    {
                <img src="@Url.Action("DispalyImage", new { id = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imgpath)})" />
                }
```

Action method Code Like this:

```
public FileContentResult DispalyImage(string id)
        {
            var path = $@"D:\WaterMark\{id}.jpg";
            byte[] imageByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

          return File(imageByteData, "jpg");
        }
```

Image is displaying fine but I want to encrypt it as Base64 so if any body download it image should be in encrypted form  please give me some idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Base64 isn’t encryption. If it’s encrypted, then the image can’t be displayed at all without providing the decryption method, in which case *what’s the point?!*

Comment: If you don't want anyone to download it don't put it on the web

Comment: Base64 encryption is working fine in chrome but image  not displayed in Internet Explorer if any one have any idea how to make it visible in IE please share

Comment: Disable the image. Then it cannot be downloaded or selected even.

Comment: base64 is **encoding**, not encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to think outside MVC and [handle in IIS itself](http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/prevent_hotlinking_url_rewrite.htm).  IIS has the tools to figure out whether or not an image request appears to have come from inside your site or not.